# Opening multiple sqlite3 connections with python multiprocessing

Tags: python, sqlite, multiprocessing

I've got a single DB file and trying to open a connection to it from multiple processes (not necessarily concurrent).

What I'm seeing is that if the DB is opened from the main process, even though the connection is closed, the same DB cannot be opened by the child process.

I've created a small example to show this:

```
import sqlite3
import multiprocessing

DB='cache.sqlite'

def connect():
    conn=sqlite3.connect(DB, check_same_thread=False, detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES,timeout=1)
    print 'Opened connection'
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

connect()
multiprocessing.Process(target=connect, args=()).start()
```

Running this prints only one 'Opened connection' as the child process fails to open it.

If I comment the connect line in the master process, the child process opens the file successfully.

What is happening?

Comment: With an empty file, I see the connection opened twice.

Comment: SQLite is known for having limitations for concurrent accesses. Above code is oversimplified and works, but as soon as you will add any modification statement, it could break.

Comment: Thanks @wrwrwr, yes, my file is indeed a populated DB.

Comment: @SergeBallesta so you're saying once a single commit has been made, the same DB cannot be open by any other process even though the connection was properly closed? This sounds absurd

Comment: SQLite has only database level locks. Only one process at a time can have an active *write* transaction. If you start only one child,  and after the parent has closed its connection it should be fine. But as soon as  different processes are active at the same time **you** will have to synchonize them to avoid the *SQLITE_BUSY* (or database in use) error. ([ref.](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html))

Comment: The problem is that your oversimplified example should not exhibit the error. Can you confirm that you get an exception with it and show the error message?

Comment: That's another thing. There is no error message. It's stuck connecting. Also, as my example shows, the connections are no opened in parallel. The first is closed before the other is opened

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I tracked the problem to mac OSX bad sqlite library.

There are numerous comments on the web about crashes/segfaults with latest bundles OSX sqlite library.

What I did was installed original sqlite using homebrew, and installed a new python with links to the original sqlite.
This seems to have solved the problem.